# List unexpected behavior - How to redraw//recreate each RowView?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have realized that some caching mechanism is present if the List's row is a View.

Let's start with a simple list:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var model = [String]()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add") {
                model.append(UUID().uuidString)
            }

            List {
                ForEach(0 ..< model.count, id:\.self) { idx in
                    let item = model[idx]
                    Print("\(idx)")
                    makeRow(item: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func makeRow(item: String) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Print("Row \(item)")
            Text("\(item)")
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func Print(_ vars: Any...) -> some View {
        for v in vars { print(v) }
        return EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Adding a new single row, this appears on the console:

```
4
Row 44899379-B7FA-4667-ADB9-86A59EA69EF0
0
Row A219638D-9C6E-42C8-9055-C5569B20D9B8
1
Row B6187186-408F-46B2-A121-840C399CB12F
2
Row 856F873F-8639-4CA4-A832-19EF92BFA7A4
3
Row 0C080275-12D9-451C-8C7A-C8B97C4DE658
```

Then each row is recreated.

Let's replace each row with a View:

```
func makeRow(item: String) -> some View {
        RowView(item: item)
}


struct RowView: View {
    var item: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Print("Row \(item)")
            Text("\(item)")
        }
    }
}
```

Now the console shows:

```
4
Row E55A0F48-5848-4CFE-8612-AB8CC799F532
0
1
2
3
```

**Only the RowView for the just added row is created.**

Apparently all the other RowViews all cached. I think this is good in most cases.

I'm working on a complex application and, in some use cases, I need to redraw all the rows.

How can I force to recreate each RowView?

Comment: Not really sure what did you mean... if you replace one view row type with other the list content is updated, if you update data represented by same view row type the list content is updated, so what do you want to recreate? It is not a UIKit, view is used only to render data, date update then it is re-rendered, data not updated then there is not sense to re-render and it is only flashed from cache. What's wrong?

Comment: @Asperi.I would like that each RowView would be recreated at each List refresh so that if something has changed in the row layout all rows are properly effected and not just the last one.

Comment: It works in different way, not started from list refresh (List > View > Data) but from data (Data > View > List), so put all layout dependency into view model, and any change in there will result in correct view row recreation and List refresh.

Comment: There are a few SwiftUI issues in your code I suggest you watch [this](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022) to clear some of it up